# Android - Fill color below the line chart

Tags: android, canvas, charts, bitmap, paint

I am building a line chart for one of our applications. The line part in the chart is working fine but now I have to fill the area below the line with a color, something like this image below.

[image]

I am using this code to draw the line on to a bitmap using a canvas.

```
    List<Float> xCoordinates = (List<Float>) coordinates[0];
    List<Float> yCoordinates = (List<Float>) coordinates[1];

    for (int i = 0; i < xCoordinates.size(); i++) {
        if (!firstSet) {
            x = xCoordinates.get(i);
            y = yCoordinates.get(i);
            p.moveTo(x, y);
            firstSet = true;
        } else {
            x = xCoordinates.get(i);
            y = yCoordinates.get(i);
            p.lineTo(x, y);
        }
    }

    textureCanvas.drawPath(p, pG);
```

What I need to know is, is there a way to easily find the area below the line and make it a color or will I have to calculate each area between 3 points for the graph and fill it with a color?

I cannot use existing chart libraries like **AchartEngine**, **ChartDroid**, **aFreeChart** ect.

Comment: I don't know that chart engine, but others. Does it have an area chart as a chart type? If so, just use the area chart and, if possible, format the upper border with a different color, to give you the appearance of a line and a fill below the line.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Found a solution

I first painted the gradient, after that I painted the line chart and erased all along the line by creating another path that followed the line chart and closed it up at the end. After that I painted the area transparent to erase the top part of the gradient.

```
    List<Float> xCoordinates = coordinates.first;
    List<Float> yCoordinates = coordinates.second;
    for (int i = 0; i < xCoordinates.size(); i++) {
        if (!firstSet) {
            x = xCoordinates.get(i);
            y = yCoordinates.get(i);
            linePath.moveTo(x, y);

            erasePath.moveTo(x, 0);
            erasePath.lineTo(x, y);

            firstSet = true;
        } else {
            x = xCoordinates.get(i);
            y = yCoordinates.get(i);
            linePath.lineTo(x, y);
            erasePath.lineTo(x, y);
        }
    }

    erasePath.lineTo(getWidth(), y);
    erasePath.lineTo(getWidth(), 0);
    erasePath.lineTo(0, 0);

    getTextureCanvas().drawPath(erasePath, clear);
    getTextureCanvas().drawPath(linePath, pG);
```

The result looked like this

[image]

Another way to do this is to follow the path exactly and clip around the bottom edges and just paint the gradient inside the second path. This will give the same result but all content above the graph will be kept and nothing will be erased.

Comment: Thanks for posting your (great) own solution, it helped me a lot!

Comment: Can you please show me the full source code to fill color below the line chart?

Comment: It's that exact code you just need to invert the erase path to follow the line path and clip at the bottom, so follow the line and then move the gradient path y to the height of the bitmap and then x back to 0;

Comment: I don't know what is coordinates.first

Comment: It's a pair. Look at this http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Pair.html